# Questions relating differentiability to continuity and integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, continuity

These questions are from Stephen Abbott's "Understanding Analysis", 7.5.2, following a brief explanation of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. I have ideas but I feel like I need help still.

Decide whether each statement is true or false, providing a short justification for each conclusion.

(a). If $h'=g$ on $[a,b]$, then $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

If I understand the question correctly, it's asking that if a function is differentiable on $[a,b]$ then the derivative has to be continuous on that interval. I have seen a counter example to this from previous questions, which is $f(x)=\{x^2 sin(1/x),  x \neq 0$,and $0, x=0 \}$

(b) If $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $g=h'$ for some $h$ on $[a,b]$

Is this asking if a function is continuous does that mean it's differentiable? Then the answer is no because $f(x)=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. But I'm not sure if I'm even reading the problem correctly.

(c) If $H(x) = \int_{a}^{x}h$ is differentiable at $c \in [a,b], $ then $h$ is continuous at $c$.

Intuition tells me yes. I can integrate a step function, for example. The result is continuous but not differentiable.

Any input or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: $b$ is true. We can explicitly construct the $h$: $h(x) = \int_a^x g(t) \ dt$ and from the FTC we conclude $h'(x) = g(x)$.

Comment: $c$ is a bit unclear. You may have a typo

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, Thank you, that was very helpful. (c) is worded correctly, there is no typo. I didn't quite get it either, but I'm going to toy around with Robert's answer and see if that helps.

Comment: It's a bit odd that we have $H(x) = \int_a^b h$, because the RHS is independent of $x$.

Comment: @Jabernet I agree with MathematicsStudent1122. You should have something like $H(x) = \int_{a}^{x}h(t) dt$.

Comment: Okay @RobertZ, you guys are right, I just edited. One little typo there, I apologize for that. I've been at this and my other classes so long I'm going cross-eyed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for (c). Consider the function $h$ which is $1$ at $0$ and it is $0$ otherwise.

What is $H(x) = \int_{-1}^{x}h(t) dt$ for $x\in [-1,1]$? 
Is $H$ differentiable at $0$?

P.S. (a) is false by your counterexample. (b) is true, see  MathematicsStudent1122's comment.

Comment: Is $H(x) = x+1$ for just $x=1$? Well, the integration gives $x+1$ and I think it's 1 just where $x=1$ and $0$ where $x \neq 0 $, this makes $H(x)$ discontinuous at one point?

Comment: The function $h(x)$ is always zero with the exception of $x=0$ where $h(0)=1$. Are you sure that $H(x)$ is the one you wrote?

Comment: I did just edit (c), there was a typo. I'm trying to understand your example, so I take it my initial comment was not correct. I see that $h$ has a single discontinuity at $0$. When I integrate from $-1$ to $x$, I get $x+1$. This is not correct?

Comment: If you integrate the function identically 0 then $H(x)$ is identically zero. If you modify the integrand at one point only, then $H$ remains the same. $H(x)$ is the area between the the graph of $h$ and the $x$-axis over the interval $[0,x]$.